# Does RSQRTSS break the dependency on the destination register?

Tags: assembly, x86, cpu-architecture, sse

Using [uiCA](https://uica.uops.info/) I produced a trace table for the following code.

```
cvtsi2ss xmm0, eax
addss xmm0, xmm0
```

https://uica.uops.info/tmp/780bce9e56ee4a718d5369deb1326215_trace.html

You can see that each `cvtsi2ss` has to wait for the previous iteration to finish because it depends on some bits (`32:127`) of `xmm0`.

However, changing `cvtsi2ss` to `rsqrtss` makes a big difference.

```
rsqrtss xmm0, xmm1
addss xmm0, xmm0
```

https://uica.uops.info/tmp/8897a7d45c8348e68279aea4d0b18e15_trace.html

Each `rsqrtss` executes in parallel with the previous iteration. I don't understand because `rsqrtss` produces an output with bits `32:127` unchanged, just like `cvtsi2ss`, so I think it should wait for any operation on the output register to finish, just like `cvtsi2ss` did.

---

After reading the answer, I ran a simple test, and it seems sure that uiCA has a bug.

[IACA](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/developer/articles/tool/architecture-code-analyzer.html) also fails to catch the output dependency.

Please correct me if the test code is wrong.

```
__asm__ (
    R"(.section .text
    .balign 16
noXor:
    mov eax, 0x3f800000
    movd xmm1, eax
    rdtscp
    shl rdx, 32
    or rax, rdx
    mov rdi, rax
    mov ecx, 1 << 30
    jmp noXor_loop
    .balign 16
noXor_loop:
    rsqrtss xmm0, xmm1
    addss xmm0, xmm0
    dec ecx
    jnz noXor_loop
    rdtscp
    shl rdx, 32
    or rax, rdx
    sub rax, rdi
    ret
    .balign 16
yesXor:
    mov eax, 0x3f800000
    movd xmm1, eax
    rdtscp
    shl rdx, 32
    or rax, rdx
    mov rdi, rax
    mov ecx, 1 << 30
    jmp yesXor_loop
    .balign 16
yesXor_loop:
    xorps xmm0, xmm0
    rsqrtss xmm0, xmm1
    addss xmm0, xmm0
    dec ecx
    jnz yesXor_loop
    rdtscp
    shl rdx, 32
    or rax, rdx
    sub rax, rdi
    ret)"
);

unsigned long long noXor(void);
unsigned long long yesXor(void);

#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
        printf("noXor: %llu yesXor: %llu\n", noXor(), yesXor());
    }
    return 0;
}
```

```
noXor: 4978836501 yesXor: 696810039
noXor: 4971780086 yesXor: 690780109
noXor: 4977293771 yesXor: 687404710
noXor: 5499602729 yesXor: 687954399
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Test on real hardware** and you'll see the expected result: `rsqrtss xmm0, xmm1` has **4 cycle latency** as part of the xmm0 -> xmm0 dependency chain.  (On my Skylake).

That's a bug in UICA.  Or actually in the https://uops.info/ data it uses - your trace includes a link to the [`rsqrtss` page on uops.info](https://www.uops.info/html-instr/RSQRTSS_XMM_XMM.html), where we can see they only measured latency for the `operand 2 → 1` case, no entry for `1 → 1`.  When that test was written, the author maybe copy/pasted the `rsqrtps` test and forgot to add a test for an output dependency.

**Without testing yourself on a real CPU, you should only be surprised if there was an actual test that measured zero latency for `1 → 1` of `rsqrtss`**.  Without such a test, the correct assumption is that the test is missing (and thus the UICA result is wrong), not that the latency is actually zero.

Many instructions don't have output dependencies on any CPUs, so it makes sense https://uops.info/ doesn't test them all.  We'd rather have `rsqrtps` latency listed as `4` than `[0:4]`, unless there are some CPUs where it's non-zero.

**It makes sense that UICA will assume no output dependency when there's no test data; that's normal for instructions without output dependencies.**

But of course `rsqrtss` *should* test latency from each operand separately to the destination.  It's non-zero, but it's at least possible in theory for a CPU to allow late forwarding for the merge target so it's wise to actually test instead of assuming it's the same as for the proper source.  (I don't know of any x86 CPUs where a single uop allows late forwarding, so different latencies from different inputs usually only happens with multi-uop instructions.  Unlike some ARM CPUs where their FMA and/or integer MAC units allow late forwarding for the addend.)

---

BTW, your reasoning is correct, `rsqrtss` does have a dependency unless the hardware does partial-register renaming for XMM regs.  But no real-word hardware does that.

PIII and Pentium-M had to write each 64-bit *half* of an XMM separately, and maybe could write one half without the other, but `rsqrtss` leaves half of that low half unmodified, thanks to Intel's short-sighted design choices.  (Now I'm curious whether Pentium-M `cvtsi2sd xmm0, eax` or `sqrtsd xmm0, xmm1` has a false output dependency.)  But current CPUs write a whole XMM register at once.

The AVX version `vrsqrtss` even takes an extra source operand to merge with, which can be separate from the destination the result is written to.

Comment: Thanks. I ran an actual test (see edit), and it seems both uiCA and IACA has a bug if the test isn't wrong.

Comment: Considering [this example](https://godbolt.org/z/qdG5GWvY6), which optimization strategy by GCC and Clang do you think is better?

Comment: @xiver77: Yeah, I ran it myself, too, on Skylake.  Interesting but not surprising that IACA has the same bug; that's certainly not the only bug in its data or models.

Comment: @xiver77: Obviously clang's.  There's already a true dependency on XMM0 because it's the first source for `rsqrtss`, so there's no need to do anything extra.  Just like how GCC and clang avoid `popcnt` and `lz/tzcnt` false deps by doing it in-place like `popcnt edi,edi` / `mov eax,edi`.  What GCC is doing is purely wasted work, zero-extending an XMM for `_mm_set_ss`.  Clang sees you're eventually going to `_mm_cvtss_f32` the result so leaves the upper elements as don't-care.

Comment: GCC also weirdly wastes a `movaps`, possibly as part of a false-dep avoidance?  It's just a mess, but at least it doesn't redo the zero-extension for each call to `r()` in GCC10 and later.  Earlier GCC redoes that work, e.g. store/reload or movd/movd.

Comment: That dependency is also missing in Intel's XED data files (https://github.com/intelxed/xed/blob/main/datafiles/xed-isa.txt). The uops.info experiments are based on these data files.